# Is it possible in Jmeter that based on the current csv row I can decide which endpoint to call?

Tags: csv, jmeter

[image]

This is my csv file data. so is it possible in Jmeter that based on the Action column i can decide which endpoint to call or which HTTP action to perform by using if else condition or switch case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, the easiest is going for [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller).

Just define the [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) (or another Test Element) with the name matching possible variable values and use `${Action}` as the "Switch Value"

Depending on the current value of the `${Action}` variable the Switch Controller will execute this or that child element

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability)

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the CSV variable into an IF loop and check if the variable matches "create", "update" or "delete".

Info on IF Loops: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage

Comment: Thanks. Switch and IF controller both works for me, but switch is a better option